# windows 7 copy files pointed to by shortcuts

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a bunch of shortcuts to files that are in various places on my hard drive.  The physical files need to be backed up.  Any ideas on how to script this?

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: This seems to me as a very open ended question, however, if you know the location of where the short cut goes to (right click on the short cut view properties) you could always back them up that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$files = gci ~\Desktop\*.lnk | %{$sh = New-Object -COM WScript.Shell}{$sh.CreateShortcut($_.fullname).Targetpath}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is reading the type of file in the directory as it's being backed up. if it's a ".lnk" you know it's a shortcut. At that point use something similar to this article:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/nl/winserverpowershell/thread/0293e186-2a21-4677-b1a5-f4e501570a98

To return the Target Path to a variable and then process that variable as if it were a file and copy the actual file.

I hope this makes sense. I have experience with PowerShell but not this exact situation. However, this is the approach I would take.